# What are the universally understood symbols for "remote computer" or "server" or "the internet"?

Tags: icons, mobile-text-entry, cloud, remote-control

I've recently came across an idea that mobile device icons are growing into a pictographic language of their own. For example the floppy drive can be considered a universally understood symbol for "Save" or "Save to persistent storage":

[image]

**I'm trying to understand if there are also widely recognized symbols for:**

- **Remote computer**, a computer in the cloud
- A remote **server** - something I'm sending my data to
- **The internet** - I'm sending something to the internet.

I'm asking this in the context of developing a "remote control" application in which a user types text into a local text field and the text is sent over the internet to a remote server where the text appears in a remote text field. I'm looking for the symbols to **help the users understand that transfer of information to remote server is taking place.**

I'm thinking of using a series of blinking dots leading to a circle with some sort of symbol inside of it, but am not sure what that symbol should be:

[image]

Comment: **the internet** and **cloud** seem to be coinciding. What user base are you targeting? Do they even have to know that `the cloud` is just a pretty name for `a bunch of remote computers` ?

Comment: The user base is really broad, this is a part of a hospital interactive system, so anyone can potentially use it.

Comment: If the user base is broad then I agree with the answer below.  Don't reveal what the cloud is made of at all.

Comment: Icons are never universal and always open to interpretation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Clouds** are becoming quite prevalent for "save this online".

[image]

You could incorporate that into your design by showing a similar icon flashing blue while it is saving, then a green check that fades away when the save is complete.

Or show an animated  "..." inside the cloud, and then show a check when the save is complete.

Comment: Awesome, I think the arrow can also be animated!

Comment: How would those two computers look like? I envisioned the old windows 95 icon, which is probably obsolete. Would those be two flat panel monitors?

Comment: I would avoid showing anything that looks like a computer at all because it isn't relevant to the task at hand.  The import information to communicate here is (1) there is a way to save my input to the cloud. (2) the cloud has it hooray! (3) something went wrong and the cloud didn't get it. try again?  --  anything else will add friction to the UI

Comment: I agree with @DaveAlger; I was thinking of the old Windows remote desktop ui (I think) where they showed something similar. The cloud is a much better concept because it is more abstract and would therefore better fit whatever context/background your users would have.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the computer icon part, since the cloud is clearly the better option.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a flat 'earth' or 'planet' icon with an arrow would do the trick. People envision the internet as a world of data and knowledge, so this would easily tell them that this is indeed related to the internet.

Comment: I would be confused at first.  Is this icon meant to sync data to a remote server, fetch an update, launch a web browser, or something else?

Comment: [Windows 95 through XP used an image of a piece of paper flying from a globe to a folder](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AFdPS.gif) to illustrate downloading.